# Adding numbers in bash

Tags: bash

I'm collecting connection accounts for two IRC servers:

```
s1a=`sockstat|grep 94.125.182.255|grep 93. -c`
echo "Budapest.Hu.Eu.Undernet.org" $s1a "connections"
s2a=`sockstat|grep 154.35.175.201|grep 93. -c`
echo "Chicago.IL.US.Undernet.Org"  "connections"
```

How can I calculate a total (so that `$total` is equal to `$s1a + $s2a`)?

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: code to

$s1a + $s2a = $total conexion

Comment: I've tried to make your question more clear to English speakers. Please let me know if I've accurately assessed your intent.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, all you need is shell arithmetic. Try

```
total=$(( $s1a + $s2a ))
```

note, no spaces around `=` sign AND defining a variable (`total`) NO leading `$`.

AND as the super-coders will remind us, you don't even need `$` on var names inside of `$(( ... ))`, hence

```
total=$(( s1a + s2a ))
echo "$total conexion"
```

To modernize the main blocks of code, I would advise against using back-tic form of cmd-substitution, and switch to

```
s1a=$(sockstat|grep 94.125.182.255|grep 93. -c)
```

If you ever need to nest your cmd-substitutions, you'll be glad you switched ;-)

IHTH